# is it possible to show only a part of the image URL in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I am using Carrierwave and S3 to allow people to upload images and the image URL is displayed as "https://myapp.s3.amazonaws.com/image/53/98ccfeca46.jpg".

I would like to do one of two things.

1. I would like to show just
   "/image/53/98ccfeca46.jpg"

or  2. Use CName to rename the URL to not show "s3.amazonaws.com" so that the image URL will be
https://myapp.com/image/53/98ccfeca46.jpg

How can I achieve these? Is it possible to cut the image URL right after .com?
I am using <%= link_to xyz.image % > to display the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a helper method for displaying the url, and use string sub to cut off the first part of the url.

So in your helpers folder, in the helper for the corresponding model, you might have a function like

```
def show_url(url)
  return url.sub("https://myapp.s3.amazonaws.com", "")
end
```

And then in your helper you would have `<%= link_to show_url(xyz.image) %>`

Or indeed something similar, but using regular expressions

```
def show_url(url)
  return url.match(/.com(.+)/)[1]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using carrierwave, you can call `.path` to retrieve the path of the image. I tried this locally and it worked fine but I'm not sure if it will work in production. Try this:

```
<%= link_to xyz.image.path %>
```

Alternatively, you can use CloudFront to server you S3 files, which allows you add a bunch of custom CNAMEs to your distribution, so you can have `assets.myapp.com/xyz.jpg`

Comment: thanks, .path does work locally. I will check it out in prod.